# Importing talend collection to postman

Tags: postman, talend

How can we import [talend](https://www.talend.com/) collection to [postman](https://www.postman.com/)? I found a way to import postman into talend but not the other way round. Is there any script or tool to do the migration?

Comment: Any updates on this? Were you able to find anything ?

Comment: no, could not find a solve.

Comment: no,i could not/

Answer (score 0):

As the json exported from talend api tester cannot be directly imported into postman, you could **write a converter to change its format so it can be accepted by postman's importer** (I hope this will be supported officially in [github](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/10469) as it's an open issue.).

An example converter in Python is here:

```py
import json

# Open and read the Talend API Tester collection JSON file
with open('export_file.json', 'r') as f:
    talend_data = json.load(f)["entities"]

# Create new Postman collection objects
for folder in talend_data:
    folder_name = folder["entity"]["name"]
    postman_collection = {
        "info": {
            "name": folder_name,
            "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
        },
        "item": [] # all subfolders
    }

    # Loop through the requests in the Talend collection and add them to the Postman collection
    for subfolder in folder["children"]:
        postman_subfolder = {
            "name": subfolder["entity"]["name"],
            "item": []
        }

        for request in subfolder["children"]:
            request = request["entity"]
            name = request["name"]
            method = request["method"]["name"]
            protocol = request["uri"]["scheme"]["name"]
            uri = protocol + "://" + request["uri"]["host"] + request["uri"]["path"]
            headers = []
            for header in request["headers"]:
                header_key = header["name"]
                header_value = header["value"]
                headers.append({
                    "key": header_key,
                    "value" : header_value,
                    "type": "text"
                })


            postman_request = {
                "name": name,
                "protocolProfileBehavior": {
                    "disableBodyPruning": "true"
                },
                "request": {
                    "method": method,
                    "header": headers,
                    "body": {
                        "mode": "formdata",
                        "formdata": []
                    },
                    "url": {
                        "raw": str(uri),
                        "protocol": protocol
                    }
                },
                "response": []
            }
            postman_subfolder["item"].append(postman_request)

        postman_collection["item"].append(postman_subfolder)


    # Write the Postman collection JSON to a file
    with open(str(folder_name) + '.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(postman_collection, f)
```